# removing 0.0 from second column in file

Tags: python, regex, awk, sed

I have a file log.txt that has the format shown below.

## log.txt

```
280,249.999441
140,0.0
140,0.0
84917,182.59465
140,0.0
72161,185.615882
304,249.998589
280,240.184619
```

I want to remove all the entries that has 0.0 in the second column.

## expected output:

```
280,249.999441
84917,182.59465
72161,185.615882
304,249.998589
280,240.184619
```

I want the simplest and fastest way to do the above. I am open to all tools.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F, '$2 != "0.0"' log.txt

280,249.999441
84917,182.59465
72161,185.615882
304,249.998589
280,240.184619
```

`-F,` sets input field separator as comma and `$2 != "0.0"` checks if 2nd column is not `0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^[^,]*,0\.0$/d' file
```

Comment: need to escape `.` else, 2nd column data like `030` will get deleted too

Answer (score 0):

A command line solution:

```
grep -v '0\.0$' log.txt
```

Comment: doesn't check if it was in 2nd column though, will need something like `grep -v '^[^,]*,0\.0$'`

Comment: Well it does check. Just try: `echo "0.0,42" | grep -v '0\.0$'`

Comment: what if there are 3 columns when `0.0` is present in 2nd column? my suggestion should have been `grep -vE '^[^,]*,0\.0(,|$)'`

Comment: Yes, in that case it doesn't scale.

Answer (score 0):

`fileinput` module will help to re-write file in-place.

```
import sys
import fileinput

for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('xyz.txt', inplace=1)):
    if '0.0' in line:
        sys.stdout.write(line.replace(line, ''))
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

**Content of xyz.txt:**

```
280,249.999441
84917,182.59465
72161,185.615882
304,249.998589
280,240.184619
```

Answer (score 0):

with `perl`

```
$ perl -F, -lane 'print if $F[1] ne "0.0"' log.txt 
280,249.999441
84917,182.59465
72161,185.615882
304,249.998589
280,240.184619
```

- `-F,` split input lines on `,` and save to `@F` array
- Then print lines where 2nd element doesn't match the string `0.0`